# Debug features on libstdc++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2010, stl

I was running my code under debug mode in VS2010 and it catched a nice error about invalid operator< which wasn't a strict weak ordering. Is there a way  to catch these errors in libstdc++ on Linux or such conservative checks are only a feature of visual studio 2010?

Comment: How could you distinguish an "error" from intended behaviour? Perhaps I *do* want to consider certain object semantically equal even though they're not binary-equal?

Comment: @Kerrek: he's not talking about equality, but "less than", and teh STL containers *require* `operator<` to implement a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @jalf: Equality means `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`. So what? If my string class compares by `return a.size() < b.size()`, I end up considering all strings of equal length equal -- who are you to say I'm not allowed to do that? (It's like picking a representative in a quotient space.)

Comment: @kerreb: did you read what I wrote? It's not a matter of what **I** say, but of what the STL containers **require**. You can define `operator<` to do *absolutely anything you like*, but if you then store your object in a `std::map`, it'll break. The map relies on the less than operator implementing a strict weak ordering, and doing otherwise means it won't be able to populate its internal tree correctly.

Comment: And nothing **I** said, and nothing the STL says prohibits `return a.size() < b.size()`. That would in fact be a perfectly valid operator. If you'd read the question you might have noticed that the OP's error was that his operator was not a strict weak ordering. Your example operator *is*, so it's hardly very relevant, is it?

Comment: If you want an example of something that'd be unusable with the STL, consider an `operator<` implemented like this, perhaps for a simple point class: `return a.x < b.x && a.y < b.y`. *That* is not a strict weak ordering, and it won't work with `std::map`.

Comment: @Jalf: I see -- so you mean if my operator doesn't define an equivalence relation, I get UB? That'd be nice to check, I agree. But I wouldn't necessarily need `<` and `==` to be compatible, would I?

Comment: @Kerrek: not afaik. The containers I can think of only use one or the other. The unordered containers obviously need the hash function and `==` to be compatible though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` should do the trick. :)

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch17s03.html#debug_mode.using.mode

Comment: To bad this makes stl not ABI compatible, it is a mess to use with libraries like boost which use stl and won't link with this flag.

Comment: @piotr: nothing is stopping you from building boost with this flag though.

Comment: boost and whatever lib that uses the STL, nontrivial business. Then it's nice that VS does without recompiling libraries, or does it?

Comment: No, you have exactly the same problem with VS. There's no way to avoid it, because the only way to perform all this debug validation is to add extra members and data structures to the STL types. And doing that inherently breaks ABI compatibility.